# Animate div positioning rearrangement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a simple push-down effect which affects the position of two containers. So far I have managed to achieve a near-desired effect using `fixed` positioning for the hidden container while changing its position to a `relative` for the opened state.

I want to apply a ***smooth transition*** to the blue `main` div, which is being pushed down by the hidden div with a class of `.sub-header`. How can I bypass the choppy rearrangement of the containers and is there a more elegant way of doing this instead of switching positioning on click? (e.g. `fixed` to a `relative` in this case)

Currently, when I switch the positioning from `fixed` to a `relative` as expected - there is a gap being produced, which is the `.sub-header`'s height.

> **NOTE:** The heights of the current divs are fixed values, but I need this to be able to handle dynamic changes in the `.sub-header` height.
>
> **NOTE:** This should be achieved by adding a custom class, not using jQuery's nested effects like `.slideToggle` etc.

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rn63nL9/1/)**.

And the simple jQuery function needed for the Fiddle share:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  $('.sub-header').toggleClass('opened');
}).stop();
```

Answer (score 2):

Make `position: relative;` and do margin top for animating

```js
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  $('.sub-header').toggleClass('opened');
}).stop();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

header,
.sub-header,
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-header {
  height: 150px;
  background: gainsboro;/*
  transform: translateY(-200%);*/
  margin-top:-150px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.opened {/*
  transform: translateY(0%);*/
  margin-top:0;
}

main {
  height: 250px;
  background: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>Header content <a href="#" class="trigger">TRIGGER</a></header>
<div class="sub-header">Sub Header content</div>
<main>Main Content</main>
```

**Update:-**

As to get `-100%` you have make it float and set all width to `100%`

```js
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  $('.sub-header').toggleClass('opened');
}).stop();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

header,
.sub-header,
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

header {
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-header {
  height: 150px;
  width:100%;
  background: gainsboro;/*
  transform: translateY(-200%);*/
  margin-top:-100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  float:left;
}

.opened {/*
  transform: translateY(0%);*/
  margin-top:0;
}

main {
  width:100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>Header content <a href="#" class="trigger">TRIGGER</a></header>
<div class="sub-header">Sub Header content</div>
<main>Main Content</main>
```

Comment: Trouble here is, I need to be able to set it at -100% value , which in this case does not work with the margin option. Set the margin to -100% and see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I misunderstood your question, but I guess there's much simpler approach to what you're trying to achieve. Try changing corresponding classes in your CSS code:

```
.sub-header {

  background: gainsboro;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .3s linear;
  transition: height .3s linear;
}

.opened {
  height: 150px;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wscourge/2fned22c/). My approach does not cover all bases, as you can see there is still text visible in the hidden container, which is going to need some additional workaround in your js or css, but I guess it is simpler than yours, considering that your `.sub-container` has fixed `height`.

**EDIT**

For non fixed height, there is workaround in my approach:

```
.sub-header {

   background: gainsboro;
   height: auto;
   max-height: 0px;
   -webkit-transition: max-height .3s linear;
   transition: max-height .3s linear;
}

.opened {
   max-height: 400px;
}
```

but it still needs to be adjusted - when you set `.opened`'s `max-height` to the lower value, `transition` is going to be slower. It is not perfect, thought it covers cases, where `.sub-container`s' heights are relatively similar.

Comment: There is the issue which I added a note about - this needs to be able to handle changes in the height of the sub-header. Sorry for this I forgot to put it up in first place.

Comment: I edited my answer, see if it is going to cover your case .

Comment: Thank You for this, but I am looking for an option where there are no limitations e.g. using max-hegiht , any height at all.

Answer (score 0):

please check this out. we can use margin for styling and keep position the same `relative`

```js
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  $('.sub-header').toggleClass('opened');
}).stop();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

header,
.sub-header,
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-header {
  height: 150px;
  background: gainsboro;
  transform: translateY(-200%);  
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  /*play with position and margin*/
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom:-200px;
}

.opened {  
  transform: translateY(0%);
  margin-bottom:0;
}

main {
  height: 250px;
  background: deepskyblue;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<header>Header content <a href="#" class="trigger">TRIGGER</a></header>
<div class="sub-header">
  <p>Sub Header content</p>
</div>
<main>Main Content</main>
```